# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

I am getting following error while running my JdbcTemplate.update for insert. I am using JDK1.8.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.createColumnMap(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper.mapRow(ColumnMapRowMapper.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$3.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:910)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:910)
    at io.bigbear.api.repository.FeatureDao.createFeature(FeatureDao.java:46)
    at io.bigbear.api.services.FeatureService.createFeature(FeatureService.java:37)
```

The following is my code, i get error at line **jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator()**:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO feature(feature, error, status, created_by, updated_by, created_dt, last_modified_dt, "
            + "job_id, entity_sk, feature_type, beNumber, osuffix) VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] { "feature_id" });
            ps.setObject(1, feature.getFeature());
            ps.setString(2, feature.getError());
            ps.setString(3, feature.getStatus());
            ps.setString(4, feature.getCreatedBy());
            ps.setString(5, feature.getUpdatedBy());
            ps.setTimestamp(6, feature.getCreatedDt());
            ps.setTimestamp(7, feature.getUpdatedDt());
            ps.setLong(8, feature.getJobId());
            ps.setString(9, feature.getEntitySk());
            ps.setString(10, feature.getFeatureType());
            ps.setString(11, feature.getBeNumber());
            ps.setString(12, feature.getOsuffix());
            return ps;
        }
    }, holder);

    long newFeatureId;
    if (holder.getKeys().size() > 1) {
        newFeatureId = (Long) holder.getKeys().get("Feature_id");
    } else {
        newFeatureId = holder.getKey().longValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, it is one of the Spring DAO dependency mismatch. Nothing wrong with the code.
Thank you.